# Bad password when unsuspending an encrypted vm in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, encryption

I have a Windows 7 VM running in VirtualBox 5.0.26 r 108824.

1. I have enabled encryption in this VM
2. I booted it up
3. It popped up the window asking me for the password
4. I entered the password and the machine booted up
5. I suspended the VM with Save to Disk
6. I restarted the VM
7. It popped up the window asking me for the password again as expected
8. I entered the password
9. It popped up the window asking me for the password again!
10. I entered the same password (I thought I might have typed it wrong but have tried this several times now)
11. I get an error:

    ```
    Bad password or authentication failure. 
        Details: A password with the given ID already exists. 
        Result Code: VBOX_E_OBJECT_IN_USE
            (0x80BB000C) 
        Component: ConsoleWrap 
        Interface: IConsole
    ```

I can shut the machine down gracefully. If I reboot it instead of unsuspending it, it asks me for the password and when I enter it, it boots normally without errors.

Why can't I unsuspend the virtual machine if it's encrypted?  What is causing the duplicate password prompt? Is there an option I need or have I done something wrong? Or should I not expect to be able to suspend encrypted VMs?

Comment: You probably can. Just ignore second passw prompt and cancel dialog asking how to shutdown. Seems to be a bug in vbox

Comment: Yes you seem to be correct, if you cancel out of the second password dialogue box and then cancel the Close Virtual Machine dialogue box, I can access the virtual machine.